# ¿Como hacer un select múltiple?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, razor

Necesito hacer un `<select>` `multiple` para listar una lista de datos que tengo en un `enums`, ¿Como puedo crear este `select` desde razor o cual seria la forma mas optima? partiendo desde el modelo, controlador para finalmente dibujarlo en la vista.

Gracias.

Comment: Buenas, te referís a un `select` tipo combobox? o a un `select multiple` tipo lista? Si lo que buscas es hacerlo tipo combo, posiblemente sea necesario que utilices alguna librería como `Select2`

Comment: Hola, necesito hacerlo tipo lista.

Comment: Te refieres a una lista de checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

buenas @vcasas depende de como lo quieras hacer si es html estático pues poniendo en atributo multiple al tag select.

De ser dinámico (cargado por el modelo) utilizando `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => xxx, xxx, new { multiple = "multiple" })`

Creo que también existe @Html.DropdownList simplemente sería mirar la docu.

Si tienes alguna duda más no dudes en contestarme.

Un saludo

Answer (score -1):

Va, una forma de incorporar una lista con múltiples opciones para seleccionar sería:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.x, Model.x, new = {@class="", @placeholder="x"})
```

Es como una ayuda que puede cumplir con las necesidades rápidas, pero recomendaría que mires la documentación para más información.

Saludos